# IPython - get rid of numpy newlines on matrix printout

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I was was looking at a matrix I had created with numpy, and noticed that when I print it out, by just entering the array name into the interpreter, numpy seems to add a new line, or hits some kind of barrier around the middle of the screen (after 3 elements in this case), and wastes alot of space there on the right. Is there a way to get it so that it uses the whole width of the cell for output, see below.

[image: numpy array]

Comment: Take a look at `set_printoptions` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html); in particular, the `linewidth` argument.

Comment: The print(prices) just added one to the first row, giving 4 before the cutoff, but @WarrenWeckesser yep, that worked, changed linewidth to 120, each row printed out in full, thank you guys very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest printing using pandas.
Even though it's not in Ipython, maybe it'll help.

```
b = np.random.random((5,15))
```

[image]

```
a = pd.DataFrame(b)

a.round(2)
```

[image]